# The RuntimeIdentifier platform 'win10-x64' and the PlatformTarget 'x64' must be compatible

Tags: publish, maui, maui-windows

When I try to publish my .NET MAUI project for Windows platform, I'm getting following error:
"Packaged .NET applications with an app host exe cannot be ProcessorArchitecture neutral. Please specify a RuntimeIdentifier or a Platform other than AnyCPU."

I've following configuration in Settings Profile: Configuration: release|AnyCPU; Framework: net7.0-windows10...; Deployment mode: Self-contained; Target runtime: win-x64

Where I need to set RuntimeIdentifier platform 'win10-x64'?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that in Visual Studio you need to go to the Configuration Manager and set a Platform other than AnyCPU

[image]

Also, with the new .NET 8 RC1, the new RuntimeIdentifier needs to be win-x64 instead of win10-x64