# Publish a MAUI app for the Microsoft Store returns a ProcessorArchitecture error

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, maui, windows-store, .net-8.0

I'm trying to publish my .NET 8 MAUI application to the Windows Store after removing the [dependency with a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77703425/dependency-issue-when-publish-a-maui-application-for-windows-store) (I can tackle the problem later).

The problem I face now is this error:

> Packaged .NET applications with an app host exe cannot be ProcessorArchitecture neutral. Please specify a RuntimeIdentifier or a Platform other than AnyCPU.

I read a few posts:

- [The RuntimeIdentifier platform 'win10-x64' and the PlatformTarget 'x64' must be compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75941440/the-runtimeidentifier-platform-win10-x64-and-the-platformtarget-x64-must-be)
- [The RuntimeIdentifier platform 'win10-x64' and the PlatformTarget 'x86' must be compatible Error in MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/859591/the-runtimeidentifier-platform-win10-x64-and-the-p)
- [[.NET 8 RC1] Error NETSDK1083 "The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win10-x86' is not recognized" displays in error list after creating a WinUI project](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/3842)

So, I opened the *Configuration Manager* and added a new configuration like that

[image]

and I tried to recreate the package but with the same error. Then, I read I have to add in the project file this line

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x86;win-x64;win-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

and this is not working; it generates a lot more errors.

The application settings looks like that

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This is a known issue about publishing windows app with the .net 8 : [dotnet publish fails on .NET SDK 8.0.100](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/37118).